# adb.exe Cannot obtain version error: Windows 10: SEPT 2016

Tags: android, version

Android studio wont display any devices due to the error 'adb.exe unable to obtain version'.

also, when I try adb.exe from the command line I will always get the error 'There was a problem starting adb. The specified module cannot be found.'

ok,

The system path has been set to the adb.exe path...
Java is version 8 update 102
Android studio .....  v 2.13
Windows 10  Intel 3.30 Ghz,   4Gig ram, x64, 32 bit

****THINGS TRIED:****

Turning of windows Defender, --> No luck

I have uninstalled and reinstalled......---> no luck

Installed SDK TOOLS --->  No luck

Uninstalled and reinstalled AGAIN  ----> no luck

copied tools from my laptop (Android studio is working on my laptop) and copied onto my desktop (same operating system etc).  --> no luck

Installed devices however they do not show.... ---> no luck

anyway......

I have copied over the file 'adb.exe' with the latest download from the zip file and still no luck.

I am not sure where to find any log files but if they are required Ill try my best to find them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the answer to this question had to do with turning on a setting in the BIOS. I forget what this setting was but I think it had something to do with allowing VTs